# Install shuf on OS X?

Tags: command-line

Ubuntu Linux has a great tool called shuf, which works like head except that it gives you ten random lines. I couldn't find it on Homebrew. What is the simplest way of installing it on OS X?

Comment: It’s part of the gnu text utilities package. Seems to be part of coreutils, but I don’t know how stuff is packaged on homebrew.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can install coreutils with `brew install coreutils`.

`shuf` will be linked as `gshuf`. Read the caveats when you install coreutils.

Comment: The caveat just seems to be that you shouldn't use the tools' proper names, but prefix them with g (like "gshuf"), right?

Comment: Yep, or optionally configure your PATH so you get what you expect.

Comment: `brew install coreutils` installs the utils with the prefix `g` by default on osx, so you can install it using the above command.

Comment: Mac OS X Catalina 10.15+, with bash enabled as the shell, does install the `shuf` command along with `gshuf`.

Answer (score 22):

Yet another solution is to learn about the tools supplied by the vendor. Certainly you could chain `jot`, `paste`, `sort`, `cut`, `head` and get the same results.

```
jot -r "$(wc -l FILE)" 1 |
paste - FILE |
sort -n |
cut -f 2- |
head -n 10
```

- jot produces a random number from 1 to the number of lines in FILE for each line
- paste pastes the random number to each line in FILE
- sort sorts numeric each line
- cut removes the random number from each line
- head outputs the first 10 lines

Comment: I really like the essence of this answer, you never know when you might want to do the same thing on another machine where you aren't able to install extra tools for whatever reason

Comment: I had never heard about `jot` before. Thanks for expanding my knowledge.

Comment: While this answer kind of works, by default jot doesn't generate that much randomness, in the current version it seems like it only generates integers from 1 to 100, so while this will give you a different ordering of lines, it will be far from the uniform ordering you'd get from `shuf`

Answer (score 12):

You can install coreutils with [Macports](https://www.macports.org) as

```
sudo port install coreutils
```

This will put GNU core utils in /opt/local/bin with a g prepended

e.g. `gshuf`

More details on the package [coreutils](https://ports.macports.org/port/coreutils/summary).

Comment: I used this one with macports, thanks.
I don't like Homebrew much

Comment: Great answer *if* you have sudo rights. I don't.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Then ask your admin - they will have made it difficult for you to do this for a reason

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sort -R`

```
$ seq 5 | sort -R
2
3
4
1
5
```

Comment: Good answer, and works for both BSD and GNU `sort`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to install `randomize-lines`(homebrew) package, which has an `rl` command which has similar functionality to shuf.

```
Usage: rl [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Randomize the lines of a file (or stdin).

  -c, --count=N  select N lines from the file
  -r, --reselect lines may be selected multiple times
  -o, --output=FILE
                 send output to file
  -d, --delimiter=DELIM
                 specify line delimiter (one character)
  -0, --null     set line delimiter to null character
                 (useful with find -print0)
  -n, --line-number
                 print line number with output lines
  -q, --quiet, --silent
                 do not output any errors or warnings
  -h, --help     display this help and exit
  -V, --version  output version information and exit
```